# PHP replace text with array inside array

Tags: php

I have a code like this

```
$str = "PHP is programing languange. I can speak English";

$replaceWith = [
[PHP,JAVA,Python],[English,Japanese,Italian]
];
```

I want the text to be replaced if have some word in array without show again that word before be like this.

*[JAVA,Python] is programing languange. I can speak [Japanese,Italian]*

Comment: Take a look at `str_replace` https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: can you give me a sample ?

Answer (score 0):

Why not split the string to array and replace them when match the condition ?

Something like this:

```
$str = "PHP is programing languange. I can speak English";
$arr = preg_split('/\s+/', $str);
$newStr = "";

foreach ($arr as $key=>$value)
  {
    if ($value == "PHP")
    {
      $value = "Java, Python";
    }
    else if ($value == "Java")
    {
      $value = "PHP, Python";
    }
    else if ($value == "Python")
    {
      $value = "Java, Python";
    }
    $newStr.= " ".$value;
  }

// Output 
// $newStr = "Java, Python is programing languange. I can speak English";
```

It's not pretty but it gets the work done.